# EF Code First - Assign Auto Incremented value if value is not manually set

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Developing a Asp.Net application with EF 6.X code first.
Consider below model:

```
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

Now I need to achieve following requirement:

When creating new record,

1. It should be able to specify the ProductId manually.
2. If value is not set for ProductId , then auto incremented value
   should be set automatically when saving the record.

What is the optimum solution for this?
Is there any built in support in EF?

This will be confusing:
Let say current Product Id is 100. And user is creating new record by manually setting the Product Id 150. So what would be the next value 101 or 151?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HiLo generator to generate ID values. HiLo generators are used to particularly solve this exact scenario, specially for distributed databases. Here is an article that shows how you can accomplish it with EF6.

http://joseoncode.com/2011/03/23/hilo-for-entityframework/

In short, you use a separate sequence table that contains last generated id value and each time a new item is saved that value is incremented.

Comment: Learned a new term HiLo generators :). Thanks! Btw is there any nuget packages / libraries exist for HiLo?

Comment: Not sure if there is nuget package or not. BTW the post linked, gives a source code as example. You can try that.

Comment: Yes, I will give a try. Thanks!